WooCommerce REST Client API - Not able to hit create orders webhook without consumer key and consumer key is hashed?
I am trying to create a webhook for orders create in a plugin settings. But unfortunately i am not able to hit the api without consumer key and consumer key in wp_woocommerce_api_keys table is hashed its not that which i got during creation of rest apis.
function wc_api_generate_api_keys($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_api_keys';

    $existing_api_key = $wpdb->get_row(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT consumer_secret FROM $table_name WHERE user_id = %d LIMIT 1", $user_id)
    );

    // Check if consumer_secret exists for the user
    if ($existing_api_key && $existing_api_key->consumer_secret) {
        $consumer_secret = $existing_api_key->consumer_secret;
    } else {
        return new WP_Error('no_consumer_secret', 'No consumer secret found for the user.');
    }

    // Generate a new consumer_key
    $consumer_key = 'ck_' . wc_rand_hash();

    // Update only the consumer_key in the WooCommerce API key table
    $wpdb->update(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'consumer_key'  => $consumer_key,
            'truncated_key' => substr($consumer_key, -7), 
        ),
        array('user_id' => $user_id)
    );

    return array(
        'consumer_key'    => $consumer_key,
        'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
    );
}


// Register the webhook
function register_wc_order_created_webhook($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $site_url) {
    $webhook_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/wordpress/webhook/order-created';
    $response = wp_remote_post("$site_url/wp-json/wc/v3/webhooks", [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$consumer_key:$consumer_secret"),
        ],
        'body' => json_encode([
            'name' => 'Webhook Orders',
            'topic' => 'order.created',
            'delivery_url' => $webhook_url,
            'status' => 'active'
        ]),
    ]);

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        error_log('Error registering webhook: ' . $response->get_error_message());
    } else {
        $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        error_log('Webhook registered successfully: ' . $response_body);
        // Decode the response to inspect it further
        $decoded_response = json_decode($response_body, true);
        error_log('Decoded response: ' . print_r($decoded_response, true));
    }
}

